# Powershell - SetAccessRuleProtection not working in script

Tags: powershell, file-permissions, ntfs

I have a script that copies folders to computers on the network but sometimes I need to set permissions to them. I tested this script below and it worked for one machine but it won't work for the others, it just hangs. Any idea why this wouldn't work?

```
# This is the file that contains the list of computers you want 
# to modify permissions to. Change this path IAW your folder structure.
$computers = gc "C:\scripts\computers.txt"

# This is the folder you want to modify.
$source = "c$\AEM"

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
if (test-Connection -Cn $computer -quiet) {
    "Modifying for $computer"
    $acl = Get-Acl \\$computer\$source
    $acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $True)

    # This is where you set the permissions you want, Modify the group (the first object) and the rights (the second object) as needed.
    $rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Administrators","FullControl", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
    $acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
    $rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Users","FullControl", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
    $acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
    Set-Acl \\$computer\$source $acl
} else {
    "$computer is not online"
}
```

}

It's pretty simple in terms of what it does. It goes out to the remote machine and leaves inheritance so I'm not overwriting anything. Then it adds permissions I have specified and should loop back until all the computers I listed in the text file have been modified. Works great when I do a copy, worked great on a single machine, but when I try it on other machines in one of our training rooms it fails on the first one. Am I missing something? I have administrative access across the network so it's not that I don't have permission to do this.

Comment: Just FYI, while the syntax that you're using for `New-Object` might be functional, it is better to understand exactly what's happening. I recommend using named parameters, so as to avoid confusing yourself and others. `New-Object -TypeName System.MyObject -ArgumentList 'arg1', 'arg2';`

Comment: Another thing to point out: why do you have a `$` in your source path? Shouldn't that be `c:\AEM`? And by the way, what error(s) are you getting exactly?

Comment: Hey Trevor. Thanks for the speedy response. I have c$ in the path because I'm accessing remote machines, example; \\b01234\c$\AEM is the folder that I need modified so I set it up to work that way (unless there's a smarter way for it to work). Also, I figured out that the problem was my impatience and I can't mark the question as answered yet. The echo notes that it is working but for 4GB folders across the network it seems to just take awhile.

Comment: Also, I believe it was your RoboCopy progress bar I've used in the past. Great stuff. Maybe I should find a way to edit the script so I can see that it's actually working.

Comment: Oh, the `$` makes sense now. Thanks for clarifying. I guess I was confused, because the `$source` variable makes me think that the "source" folder structure would have been local. Thanks for your compliment on the Robocopy progress bar script. :) It was a fun exercise for me. So, is this issue solved? If not, can you point out specifically where the process is failing? Cheers

Comment: Yeah it's resolved, I just can't mark it as answered since I'm a newbie still. The problem was that it was just taking awhile and I thought it wasn't working. Just jumped to the site assuming I broke something. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Well, there aren't any answers posted, so that's why you can't accept one. These are just comments. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script actually works as intended, with large files though and no progress bar it seemed like it wasn't doing anything. Applied an echo and progress bar.